# In JS how do you access the next "object" in a for...of loop

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

I'm basically trying to build a site that shows data from an API. I use the following Async function to get the data:

```
async function getapi(url) {
   //store response
   const response = await fetch(url);
   
   //store data in JSON
   var data = await response.json();
   getData(data);
}
```

In my getData function, I have have the following:

```
for(let r of data.rounds) {
  let round = r.names.shortName;
  let nextRound = //no idea how to get the name of the next round
```

This returns the round that I'm currently in (R1 in the first loop). Essentially what I want is the next rounds shortName. (so I want R2 in the first loop).
Is there any way to access the next loop's data?

console.log(r) shows:
[console.log of R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENCdC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loop instead of [`forof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) loop. It alows you to check next index of the array and use it as below.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.rounds.length; i++) {
    const round = data.rounds[i];
    const name = r.names.shortName;
    let nextRound =  data.rounds[i + 1];
    if (nextRound) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked.... I dont know why I didn't think of using a for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a cleaner implementation

```
data.rounds.map((item, index, self) => {
   let round = r.names.shortName;
   let nexObj = self[index+1]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the plain `for` example with index access is obviously cleaner. Just for fun or if you're really stuck with `for of` (some iterable data structure without random access).

```js
let prevRound

for (let r of data.rounds) {
  if (prevRound) name = prevRound.names.shortName
  // nextRound = r at this point, obviously
  ...
  prevRound = r
}
```

Comment: this is genius, but it would require me to re-write all of my other logic. Gonna go with regular for loop. Thanks for answering tho!

Answer (score -1):

If you need the next element in one loop cycle you can use indexes as guys have already answered. If you mean how to do iteration - you don't need to do "i++" iteration etc. for.. of loop will start next cycle after body has being finished.

Alternative:

```
    for(let r of data.rounds) {
       let round = r.names.shortName;
       let nextIndex = data.indexOf(r) + 1;
       if(nextIndex <= data.length){
          let nextRound = data[nextIndex];
       }   
}
```